# Split String in Shell Script to get different combinations

Tags: bash

Please help. Split string `a b c d` to provide combinations of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `ab`, `bc`, `cd`, `abc`, `bcd` using bash?

String can be of any length with spaces.

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider appending your question with the attempts you have made so far.

Comment: Also, you might see something useful [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204069/all-possible-combinations-of-characters-and-numbers) and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123800/shell-script-to-find-the-combination-of-the-array-elements)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

string='a b c d'
separator=' '
# get number of elements
array=(${string//$separator/$IFS})
elements=${#array[@]}
# remove separators
string="${string//$separator/}"

for ((len = 1; len < $elements; len++))
do
    for ((off = 0; off < $elements - len + 1; off++))
    do
        echo ${string:$off:$len}
    done
done
```

This should work for most `$separator`s, not only space.

Comment: The output `a$
$
b$
$
a$
b$
b$
a b$
b$` ($ means newline) does not look like what the OP requested.

Comment: It doesn't work because `string=${string//$IFS/}` fails to remove the spaces from the string if `$IFS` contains more characters than just one space, which is normally the case (`IFS=$' \t\n'`).

Comment: Definitely better!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

input="ab cd   ef gh"                   ## input data

                                        ## v1: consider a b c ... as atoms
s=`sed 's:\s*::g' <<<"$input"`          ## remove all spaces
l=${#s}                                 ## l = length of s
for ((i=0;++i<l;)); do                  ## i = length of substring
  for ((j=-1;++j+i<=l;)); do            ## j = pos of substring
    echo ${s:$j:$i}                     ## print substring
  done
done | sed ':a;N;s/\n/, /;ba'           ## sed to join lines, \n => ,

                                        ## v2: consider ab cd ef ... as atoms
IFS=' ' read -r -a a <<<"$input"        ## put atoms in array
l=${#a[@]}
for ((i=0;++i<l;)); do
  for ((j=-1;++j+i<=l;)); do
    echo ${a[@]:$j:$i}|sed 's:\s*::g'   ## remove spaces when print
  done
done | sed ':a;N;s/\n/, /;ba'
```

Results:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, ab, bc, cd, de, ef, fg, gh, abc, bcd, cde, def, efg, fgh, abcd, bcde, cdef, defg, efgh, abcde, bcdef, cdefg, defgh, abcdef, bcdefg, cdefgh, abcdefg, bcdefgh
ab, cd, ef, gh, abcd, cdef, efgh, abcdef, cdefgh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $ st="a b c d"
  $ eval echo $(echo "${st}" | sed -e 's/[^ ]\+/{&,}/g' -e 's/ //g')
  abcd abc abd ab acd ac ad a bcd bc bd b cd c d
```

Use nested brace exapnsion `{ ,}` to expand and combine the letters in the string. `sed` is used to take the string and transform the input to a formar `{a,}{b,}{c,}{d,}`. Then use `eval` to evaluate the entire command that followed as if you would have tried on a cmdline.

I am not sure whether commas `,` are a requirement for the output, but that can be achieved easily by piping it to `tr`. Something like this

```
$ eval echo $(echo "${st}" | sed -e 's/[^ ]\+/{&,}/g' -e 's/ //g') | tr ' ' ','
abcd,abc,abd,ab,acd,ac,ad,a,bcd,bc,bd,b,cd,c,d
```

This should also work for words inside the string separated by space.

```
$ st='lorem ipsum dolor'
$ eval echo $(echo "${st}" | sed -e 's/[^ ]\+/{&,}/g' -e 's/ //g') | tr ' ' ','  
loremipsumdolor,loremipsum,loremdolor,lorem,ipsumdolor,ipsum,dolor
```

Comment: Nice idea. To remove the first item, and add commas: `eval echo $(sed -e 's/[^ ]\+/{&,}/g;s/ //g' <<<"$st")|sed -E 's/^[^ ]* //;s/ +/, /g'`